# Make PageRouteBuilder animate just after current page animation finishes animating in flutter

Tags: flutter, animation

I am trying to animate navigation between two pages. I managed to animate the loading of the second page by following [Reso Coder's Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7CAMPdUu8o). But I also needed to animate "exiting" animation for the current page.

I managed to achieve it using Animated Widget (`stanim`). When a user clicks on the navigation button, I just start the animation, and when the animation finishes it runs the navigation code. This works somewhat like what I needed but the animation looks janky when page animation finishes and PageRouteBuilder animation starts.

```
_controller = AnimationController(
    vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: duration))
  ..addStatusListener(
    (status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        if (widget.nextPageBuilder != null) {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            PageRouteBuilder(
              transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: duration),
              pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) =>
                  widget.nextPageBuilder(animation),
            ),
          );
        }
      }
    },
  );
```

Here is navigation logic

```
return ForwardButton(onPressed: () {
      _controller.forward();
});
```

Comment: *"Make PageRouteBuilder animate just after current page animation finishes animating in flutter"* - so you want to go to another page (`Navigator.push`) and when the "route transition animations" finish you want to run another animation or something else?

Comment: I want to animate the current page exiting and the new page coming forth in one smooth animation. Currently, I am running page exiting animation, navigating to another page, and running page loading animation. @pskink

Comment: so why dont you use the default `MaterialPageRoute`? the docs say: *"A modal route that replaces the entire screen with a platform-adaptive transition.

For Android, the entrance transition for the page slides the route upwards and fades it in. The exit transition is the same, but in reverse.

The transition is adaptive to the platform and on iOS, the route slides in from the right and exits in reverse. The route also shifts to the left in parallax when another page enters to cover it. (These directions are flipped in environments with a right-to-left reading direction.)"*

Comment: I need custom animations. @pskink

Comment: this is what `PageTransitionsTheme` is used for - the docs say: *"Defines the page transition animations used by MaterialPageRoute for different TargetPlatforms.

The MaterialPageRoute.buildTransitions method looks up the current current PageTransitionsTheme with Theme.of(context).pageTransitionsTheme and delegates to buildTransitions."*

Comment: Ok, I did few google searches. It looked promising. Can you give me any tips on how can we achieve something like [Hero animation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/hero-animations) where there is a common widget on both pages, and that widget does seamless transition between page? My requirements are similar to it. @pskink

Comment: so if you have a common widget then you need to use `Hero` animations - you cannot have such thing with "page transitions"